# translate raw query to cakephp

Tags: sql, cakephp-2.0

Could please anybody tell me how to convert this raw query into Cakephp 2.x

```
SELECT idUser, email, username, 
    (select count(room.idRoom)  FROM room as room where winner1 = user.idUser or winner2 = user.idUser) as t
    FROM 
    PRODB.user as user
    order by t desc
    ;
```

Answer (score 0):

some time in cakephp we have to add raw query as inline.. i hope this may helpful to you.

```
$rs = $this->User->query("SELECT idUser, email, username, (select count(room.idRoom) FROM room as room where winner1 = user.idUser or winner2 = user.idUser) as t FROM  PRODB.user as user order by t desc");
```